# Duplicated data for serialize with "all selector" and with fieldset

Tags: jquery

Please see the problem online (using FireBug console) - http://jsfiddle.net/ihtus/3DuPW/

```
<div id='mydiv1'>
    this is with fieldset and $('#mydiv1 *').serialize()<br/>
    <fieldset><legend>aa</legend>
        <input type='text' name='myinp' value=''>
        <input id='save' type='button' value='serialize' onclick="console.log($('#mydiv1 *').serialize())">
    </fieldset>
    <br/>result: myinp=myval&myinp=myval
</div>
<br/><br/>

<div id='mydiv2'>
    this is without fieldset and $('#mydiv1 *').serialize()<br/>
    <input type='text' name='myinp' value=''>
    <input id='save' type='button' value='serialize' onclick="console.log($('#mydiv2 *').serialize())">
    <br/>result: myinp=myval
</div>
<br/><br/>

<div id='mydiv3'>
    this is with fieldset and $('#mydiv1 :input').serialize()<br/>
    <fieldset><legend>aa</legend>
        <input type='text' name='myinp' value=''>
        <input id='save' type='button' value='serialize' onclick="console.log($('#mydiv3 :input').serialize())">
    </fieldset>
    <br/>result: myinp=myval
</div>
```

### Question

Why when having `$('#mydiv1 *').serialize()` and fieldset => the result is duplicated "myinp=myval&myinp=myval"

There is no duplication when having `$('#mydiv1 *').serialize()` and NO fieldset.

I know I should use `$('#mydiv1 :input').serialize()`, and I will use it... but I am just curious why the data is duplicated in that certain case.

Comment: Using the ALL selector gives you the values from mydiv1 and mydiv2 and mydiv3 in which you have inputs with the exact same name. Can you show your actual jQuery code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ihtus/3DuPW/

Comment: Jay Blanchard: I think you don't understand my question, please read my q again.

Comment: First I would only use the ALL selector in very specific circumstances - certainly not like you're using it here.

Comment: Jay Blanchard: I've already mentioned that I will not use all selector, I just want to understand why duplication is happening.

Comment: That is an easy question to answer - you're getting #mydiv1 container AND the fieldset container. If you place a comma in the selector you'll get myinp= 5 times, twice for each div with a fieldset and once for the one without.

Comment: Jay Blanchard: why I am not getting duplicates if I will have a div instead of fieldset? (<div id='mydiv1'><div>inputs..</div></div>)

Comment: Jay Blanchard: any jsfiddle?

Comment: Because of the way that fieldsets are treated in markup as a whole. They're not like other markup in as much as they are meant to group controls.

Comment: It really doesn't need another fiddle, just add the comma like this $(' #mydiv1, * ') to the selector.